# Run a script after every grub-update

Tags: boot, grub2, scripts

I want to run a script automatically after every grub-update. The script itself consists of a single line

```
sed -i 's/[\]"!Windows 2006[\]"/"!Windows 2006"/g' /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

For this purpose, I edited the already existing file

```
/etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

to read as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
sed -i 's/[\]"!Windows 2006[\]"/"!Windows 2006"/g' /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

This, however doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Just add a line like `touch /tmp/grubtest` and run `update-grub`.  Is the file create?

Comment: Scripts in `/etc/grub.d` are run as part of creating `grub.cfg`. I doubt you can process that file while it is being created.

Comment: I tried to edit the `/usr/sbin/update-grub` and the `/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig` which it executes and add a simple `echo` command to each of the scripts, but they were not processed for some reason. Are those scripts cached somewhere so that the changes did not affect the executed commands or is anything in there that terminates the script before reaching the last line?

Comment: @davidbaumann `touch /tmp/grubtest` works just fine. @muru maybe you are right. do you guys have some alternative?

Comment: Just add `cp /boot/grub/grub.cfg /tmp/grub.cfg`. So you can see what's inside the grub file after running sed.

Comment: Editting the file `/tmp/grub.cfg` works as it should. The problem is that I, apparently, cannot overwrite `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` from within the script.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is add your script file to `/etc/grub.d` and make it executable. They are executed in shell expansion order.

For example, add this as `/etc/grub.d/90_my_script`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo this is a test >/home/brian/1
>&2 echo this is stderr output
```

The stdout seems to be captured, but you could use the logger to add something to syslog, or echo to stderr.

Comment: That's half of truth, please see [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1506041/590937)

Answer (score 1):

`update-grub` is a small shell-script that just calls another shell-script `grub-mkcnfig` withe some options:

```
$ cat /sbin/update-grub
#!/bin/sh
set -e
exec grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg "$@"
```

Let's take a look at the very last lines of `grub-mkconfig`:

```
if test "x${grub_cfg}" != "x" ; then
  if ! ${grub_script_check} ${grub_cfg}.new; then
    # TRANSLATORS: %s is replaced by filename
    gettext_printf "Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
%s file attached." "${grub_cfg}.new" >&2
    echo >&2
    exit 1
  else
    # none of the children aborted with error, install the new grub.cfg
    cat ${grub_cfg}.new > ${grub_cfg}
    rm -f ${grub_cfg}.new
  fi
fi
```

This looks as if `grub-mkconfig` creates a temporay file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new` which is at the end checked for correct syntax, then copied to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and at last removed.

You should not use your `sed`-command in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` since the content of this file will be copied to the new configuration file (exept the first two lines) and you don't want the `sed`-command in the  new configuration file.

The purpose of `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` is to add custom menu entries to `grub.cfg` which will be copied to the configuration file by the use of the `exec tail`-command in the second line. So the `sed`-command would appear in `grub.cfg` and lead to a syntax error since `sed` is not a valid grub-command. Of course, you could remove the `exec tail`-command from `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` but if you have any custom menu entries added here this is not what you want to do.

Instead, use a different file in `/etc/grub.d/` as suggested in [brianc's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1505906/590937), for example `/etc/grub.d/90_my_sed_command`. Don't forget to make the file executable (`sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/90_my_sed_command`)

And you need to use your `sed`-command on the temporary file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new` instead of using it with `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` which is the old config file and will be overwritten with the new configuration file after a succesful syntax check:

```
sed -i 's/[\]"!Windows 2006[\]"/"!Windows 2006"/g' /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new
```

I didn't check your `sed`-command, if it somehow produces invalid syntax the syntax check will fail, the old `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` will not be overwritten and you will get the error message which you can see in the snippet of `grub-mkconfig` I posted above.

---

The question is nine years old,this answer should be valid for recent versions of Ubuntu, I tested it on Ubuntu 22.04.3.

I created a file /etc/grub.d/42_sed with the content

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -i s/"'Ubuntu"/"'Ubuntustudio"/ /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new
```

and made it executable. I issued `sudo update-grub` after backing up my original `grub.cfg`.
The line with

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu (lowlatency)'
```

in the backed up original configfile `gub.cfg.bak` changed to

```
menuentry 'Ubuntustudio (lowlatency)'
```

in the newly created configfile `grub.cfg`. Quod erat demonstrandum...